# Follow object rotation but with a limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that follows the rotation of another object. I want this object to have a limit while rotating in X and Y axis. How do I use clamp in such a case?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToFollow;
    public float minY;
    public float maxY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(objectToFollow.transform.eulerAngles.x, Mathf.Clamp(objectToFollow.transform.eulerAngles.y, minY, maxY), this.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

I am trying to do it for Y axis as shown in the code, but it does not work. It stays fixed in the maximum rotation limit and does not rotate less or above than that.

Comment: Works perfectly fine when I test it. By any chance, have you assigned the minY and maxY floats in the inspector?

Comment: I closed this question as you seem to have changed your mind anyway and your new question seems to make this one redundant